# Adding a case to an existing enum with a protocol

Tags: swift, enums, protocols

I want to create a `protocol` that enforces a certain case on all `enums` conforming to this `protocol`.

For example, if I have a `enum` like this:

```
enum Foo{
    case bar(baz: String)
    case baz(bar: String)
}
```

I want to extend it with a `protocol` that adds another case:

```
case Fuzz(Int)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## Design

The work around is to use a `struct` with `static` variables.

Note: This is what is done in **Swift 3** for `Notification.Name`

Below is an implementation on **Swift 3**

## Struct:

```
struct Car : RawRepresentable, Equatable, Hashable, Comparable {

    typealias RawValue = String

    var rawValue: String

    static let Red  = Car(rawValue: "Red")
    static let Blue = Car(rawValue: "Blue")

    //MARK: Hashable

    var hashValue: Int {
        return rawValue.hashValue
    }

    //MARK: Comparable

    public static func <(lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {

        return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }

}
```

## Protocol

```
protocol CoolCar {

}

extension CoolCar {

    static var Yellow : Car {

        return Car(rawValue: "Yellow")
    }
}

extension Car : CoolCar {

}
```

## Invoking

```
let c1 = Car.Red


switch c1 {
case Car.Red:
    print("Car is red")
case Car.Blue:
    print("Car is blue")
case Car.Yellow:
    print("Car is yellow")
default:
    print("Car is some other color")
}

if c1 == Car.Red {
    print("Equal")
}

if Car.Red > Car.Blue {
    print("Red is greater than Blue")
}
```

## Note:

Please note this approach is not a substitute for `enum`, use this only when the values are not known at compile time.

Comment: Why leave `protocol CoolCar` empty, just to extend it...?

Comment: This is just to show that it is possible to extend and this solution would work even with an extension. CoolCar might be defined in a framework (example: Standard Library / Foundation) and you might not be able to directly modify it. You can extend it and this solution would still work

Comment: How can we make case like Car.Red(parameter: String) from this structure?

Comment: Issue is that now you will need to always define default for switch.

Comment: that switch won't work with uitableview. If I do the same and I need to have switch in cellforrow to check what section it is, it won't work

Answer (score 13):

no, since you can't declare a `case` outside of an `enum`.

Answer (score 7):

An `extension` can add a nested `enum`, like so:

```
enum Plants {
  enum Fruit {
     case banana
  }
} 


extension Plants {
  enum Vegetables {
     case potato
  }
}
```

Comment: How would I assign a variable with banana or potato? And what would the type of that variable be?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple additional takes that may help somebody out there:

Using your example:

```
enum Foo {
    case bar(baz: String)
    case baz(bar: String)
}
```

You can consider to "nest" it in a `case` of your own `enum`:

```
enum FooExtended {
    case foo(Foo) // <-- Here will live your instances of `Foo`
    case fuzz(Int)
}
```

With this solution, it becomes more laborious to access the "hidden" cases associated type. But this simplification could actually be beneficial in certain applications.

Another alternative passes by just recreate and extend it while having a way to convert `Foo` into the extended `enum` `FooExtended` (eg. with a custom `init`):

```
enum FooExtended {
    case bar(baz: String)
    case baz(bar: String)
    case fuzz(Int)

    init(withFoo foo: Foo) {
        switch foo {
        case .bar(let baz):
            self =  .bar(baz: baz)
        case .baz(let bar):
            self = .baz(bar: bar)
        }
    }
}
```

There may be many places where one, the other, or both of these solutions make absolutely no sense, but I'm pretty sure they may be handy to somebody out there (even if only as an exercise).

Answer (score 0):

In our app, we must use (or by very strong convention we use) enums. Rather than switch away from this, to enforce a rule that ensures the existence of

```
case fuzz(Int)
```

in all enums that adopt this protocol, I opted for enforcing the existence of a static func that *generates* what is effectively this case, and accepts the Int for which this case is to act as a carrier. Thus:

```
protocol HasIntCarryingCase {
    static func carryInt(int: Int) -> Self
}
```

To adopt and implement this in a particular enum, I would write, for instance:

```
enum Foo: HasIntCarryingCase {
    case bar(bar: String)
    case baz(baz: String)
    case fuzz(fuzz: Int)
    static func carryInt(int: Int) -> Self { .fuzz(fuzz: int) }
}
```

In this way, at the call site where a piece of code wants to *make* this case and populate it with its Int, it would simply call `carryInt` instead, handing it the Int to be carried. This call can be used wherever a Foo instance is expected, exactly as if it were an actual case! Thus:

```
let myIntCarrying: Foo = .carryInt(int: 42)
```

In my particular usage there was no need to ask the enum for the carried Int agnostically of the actual case name, because the name of the desired case is known at the call site. But it is obvious how you could, if you needed to, make another `func` (not `static` but normal) that extracts the Int from this special Int-carrying case. The Int would need to wrapped as an Optional, to handle the situation where this particular instance of the enum is not the Int-carrier.