# Is it possible to guarantee that the enums has a specific case?

Tags: swift, enums

I have a protocol:

```
protocol ReduxTransition {}
```

I have a enums:

```
enum ProfileTransition: ReduxTransition {
   case authorization
   ...
   case showNotification(NotificationType)
} 

enum RatingTransition: ReduxTransition {
   case pop
   ...
   case showNotification(NotificationType)
}
```

And I want to do stuff like this to avoid using similar implementations for showing notifications

```
func processError(performTransition: @escaping (ReduxTransition) -> ()) {
   var notification: NotificationType!
   performTransition(.showNotification(notification))
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? If only one type would be allowed then drop the type alltogether and simply pass in the notification itself without the num.

Comment: I tried to extend my question

Comment: Still no idea what you are actually asking: `performTransition(notification)` and `func processError(performTransition: @escaping (NotificationType) -> ()) {` works.

Comment: I can't initiate transitions without using enums in my redux implementation.
All transitions from a specific screen should be encapsulated in enum.
And they can only initiated by using the block `performTransition: @escaping ([ModuleName]Transition) -> Void`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I applied the following solution:

```
protocol NotificationPresentable {
   static func getNotificationTransition(of type: NotificationType) -> Self
}

extension ProfileTransition: NotificationPresentable {
   static func getNotificationTransition(of type: NotificationType) -> ProfileTransition {
       return .showNotification(type)
   }
}

extension RatingTransition: NotificationPresentable {
   static func getNotificationTransition(of type: NotificationType) -> RatingTransition {
       return .showNotification(type)
   }
}

func processError<Transition: NotificationPresentable>(performTransition: @escaping (Transition) -> ()) {
   let notification: NotificationType!
   ...
   performTransition(Transition.getNotificationTransition(of: notification))
}
```

Maybe someone knows how to make this solution even more better?

Comment: For comparison, here's a similar solution completely independently arrived at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77595350/341994