# Is it possible to write a Swift Extension for UIDatePicker.Mode

Tags: swift, enums, uidatepicker, swift-extensions

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/mode), `UIDatePicker.Mode` is an `enum` of type `Int` with four cases.

```
enum Mode : Int

case time
case date
case dateAndTime
case countDownTimer
```

I am curious to know whether I can add a fifth `case monthYear` (= 4) to enable me to create a custom implementation of UIDatePicker.

The purpose of this fifth case would be to display only the month and year rollers in the picker control.

(Please note that I am aware that I could - and probable will - create a custom `UIPickerView` to handle this, however I am curious to know whether I can gracefully extend `UIDatePicker` class or `UIDatePicker.Mode` enum to achieve this.)

I've done some reading on writing an `extension` for an `enum`. I've read some interesting articles and reviewed a few Stack Overflow Q&A that include functioning workarounds...

- [Adding a case to an existing enum with a protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34025674/1883707)
- [How to add more cases for enum in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53113895/1883707)
- [Can an enum contain another enum values in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40665509/1883707)
- [Swift enum inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33191532/1883707)
- [Why Choose Struct Over Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24232799/1883707)

So in my humble opinion, to be able to neatly extend `UIDatePicker`, I'd need to first be able to extend `UIDatePicker.Mode`.

I've also read in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker) under the heading *Appearance*...

> The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable.

This seems fairly definitive to me, however it does not hurt to ask the question...

Is it possible to write a Swift Extension for `UIDatePicker.Mode` so that I can add a fifth `case monthYear` and for `UIDatePicker` so that I can write a custom implementation that shows just month and year rollers in the control?

Comment: Even if you could add an additional case to the enum, the date picker class would not know how to render itself based on the new mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not modify the functionality of `UIDatePicker` to support your own custom mode.

You either need to implement your own custom date picker using `UIPickerView` or find a 3rd party component that has already done so.